# Change the font in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

Can you help me to compile this pie diagram with this document class.

**main.tex**

```
\documentclass[]{cv-style}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Diagram
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[text=white, border/.style={line width=14mm}]
  \foreach \angle/\col [remember=\angle as \last (initially 1)] in 
    {90/blue, 162/red, 234/green, 288/purple, 342/orange, 360/aquamarine}{
      \draw[\col, border] (\last:2cm) 
          arc[start angle=\last, end angle=\angle, radius=2cm];
      \draw[white, line width=1mm] (\last:1.3)--++(\last:1.4);
  }
  \node[line width=1mm, draw, circle, white, minimum width=2.5cm, fill=lightgray] {\large C/C++};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (50:2cm) {C\# (.NET)};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (130:2cm) {Java};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (195:2cm) {JS};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (260:2cm) {PHP HTML CSS};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (315:2cm) {SQL};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (353:2cm) {Scripts};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

**cv-style.cls**

```
\ProvidesClass{cv-style}[2015/02/27 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{tikz}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Définition des couleurs
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{C0C0C0}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{303030}
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}

\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{1DB1FC}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{DC3912}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FF9900}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{109618}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{9358FE}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{HTML}{0C343D}

\definecolor{date}{HTML}{A4A4A4}

\colorlet{fillheader}{white}
\colorlet{namecolor}{black}
\colorlet{headercolor}{black}
\colorlet{headerSub}{darkgray}
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Définition des polices
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont
[BoldFont=texgyreheros-bold.otf,
ItalicFont=texgyreheros-italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=texgyreheros-bolditalic.otf]
{texgyreheros-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\bodyfont{Roboto-Regular}[Path=fonts/]
\newfontfamily\bodyfontit{Roboto-LightItalic}[Path=fonts/]
\newfontfamily\thinfont{Roboto-Thin}[Path=fonts/]
\newfontfamily\headingfont{RobotoCondensed-Bold}[Path=fonts/]

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor, Path = fonts/]{Roboto-Light}

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\headingfont\color{headerSub}}

\newcommand{\italica}[1]{%
    {\color{gray}\bodyfontit #1}%
}
```

---

You can find it [here](https://www.overleaf.com/5081713cvvsfx).

Comment: You should use `xelatex` and not `pdflatex`. You can compile it in your PC or try to do it on `overleaf`.

Comment: I got the same problem with xelatex.

Comment: And the problem is?

Comment: I can't apply the font correctly to the diagram.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass the font option to your `tikzpicture`, using `font=` somewhere within the square brackets.

I don't have the Roboto fonts, so I've used Baskerville to demonstrate.

[image]

```
\begin{filecontents}{cv-style.cls}
\ProvidesClass{cv-style}[2015/02/27 CV class]
\NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}

\ProcessOptions\relax
\LoadClass{article}

\RequirePackage{tikz}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Définition des couleurs
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{white}{RGB}{255,255,255}

\definecolor{lightgray}{HTML}{C0C0C0}
\definecolor{gray}{HTML}{303030}
\definecolor{darkgray}{HTML}{333333}

\definecolor{blue}{HTML}{1DB1FC}
\definecolor{red}{HTML}{DC3912}
\definecolor{orange}{HTML}{FF9900}
\definecolor{green}{HTML}{109618}
\definecolor{purple}{HTML}{9358FE}
\definecolor{aquamarine}{HTML}{0C343D}

\definecolor{date}{HTML}{A4A4A4}

\colorlet{fillheader}{white}
\colorlet{namecolor}{black}
\colorlet{headercolor}{black}
\colorlet{headerSub}{darkgray}
\colorlet{textcolor}{gray}


%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Définition des polices
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\RequirePackage[quiet]{fontspec}
\RequirePackage[math-style=TeX,vargreek-shape=unicode]{unicode-math}

\newfontfamily\bodyfont
[BoldFont=texgyreheros-bold.otf,
ItalicFont=texgyreheros-italic.otf,
BoldItalicFont=texgyreheros-bolditalic.otf]
{texgyreheros-regular.otf}
\newfontfamily\bodyfont{Baskerville}
\newfontfamily\bodyfontit{Baskerville Italic}
\newfontfamily\thinfont{Baskerville}
\newfontfamily\headingfont{Baskerville SemiBold}

\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\setmainfont[Mapping=tex-text, Color=textcolor]{Avenir Next}

\renewcommand{\bfseries}{\fontsize{11pt}{11pt}\headingfont\color{headerSub}}

\newcommand{\italica}[1]{%
    {\color{gray}\bodyfontit #1}%
}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass[]{cv-style}

%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Diagram
%-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[text=white, border/.style={line width=14mm},font=\bodyfontit]
  \foreach \angle/\col [remember=\angle as \last (initially 1)] in 
    {90/blue, 162/red, 234/green, 288/purple, 342/orange, 360/aquamarine}{
      \draw[\col, border] (\last:2cm) 
          arc[start angle=\last, end angle=\angle, radius=2cm];
      \draw[white, line width=1mm] (\last:1.3)--++(\last:1.4);
  }
  \node[line width=1mm, draw, circle, white, minimum width=2.5cm, fill=lightgray] {\large C/C++};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (50:2cm) {C\# (.NET)};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (130:2cm) {Java};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (195:2cm) {JS};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (260:2cm) {PHP HTML CSS};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (315:2cm) {SQL};
  \node[text width=1cm, align=center] at (353:2cm) {Scripts};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why your code doesn't work with my police?

Comment: You need to build with XeLaTeX, not pdflatex, and you need to have the Baskerville fonts installed. If you don't have them, you can easily change them to something else. The point is you need to add something like `font=\bodyfontit` to your `tikzpicture` options.

Comment: How can I install a font when I'm using Overleaf?

Comment: @hlapointe I don't know. Try their [help pages](https://www.overleaf.com/help/73-i-have-a-custom-font-id-like-to-load-to-my-document-how-can-i-do-this)